# Как создать ветку с прошлой версией продукта

Tags: gitlab, git-merge, branch

У меня есть проект на gitlab. В проекте есть несколько mileston'ов, например v1, v2, v3...v56. Сейчас актуальная версия это 56. Но предположим, заказчик не хочет пользоваться 56 версией, а например хочет 45 версию. Но при этом, он хочет добавить часть функционала из 56.

Как мне создать ветку с нужной версией проекта, чтобы туда добавлять изменения?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось разобраться. Для этого достаточно при создании мерж реквеста в поле "Source (branch or tag)" указать нужный milestone.